# extract strings with more than n words from list

Tags: r, regex

I have a long list of strings (about 9 million) like this:

```
[1] ""                                                                                                                  
[2] "Hij is op 22 oktober 2001 getrouwd"
[3] ""                                                                                                                  
[4] " Biografie test"
```

I need to select every string that has more than n words. I have been trying:

```
string <- c("", "Hij is op 22 oktober 2001 getrouwd", "", " Biografie ")
grepl("\\w{3,}", string, perl = T)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

To my mind, `\\w{3,}` should find everything that has n = three or more words, but for some reason it also matches the 4th with just two words. I have also tried things like `(\\s\\w\\s){3,}`, `(\\w\\s){3,}`, `(\\b\\.+\\b){3,}` and `(\\w+\\b){3,}`. But nothing with the desired result.

Should be simple, but can't figure it out. Anyone?

Comment: `\\w` matches **word characters** not words. So your grep is matching strings with three or more word characters in a row, which your two non-empty strings satisfy.

Comment: Ok, but why wouldn't `(\\w+\\b){3,}` work then? It would say it selects one or more word characters plus a boundary, at least three times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple grep that should suit your needs:

```
string <- c("", "Hij is op 22 oktober 2001 getrouwd", "", " Biografie ")
grepl("(\\w+\\s){3,}", string)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

or...

```
sapply(strsplit(string, "\\s"), length)>=3  
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Ah! I knew I was close :) `(\\w+\\s){3,}` was exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `stri_count` from package `stringi` to count words:

```
library(stringi)
string <- c("", "Hij is op 22 oktober 2001 getrouwd", "", " Biografie ")
stri_count(string,regex="\\S+")
[1] 0 7 0 1
```

To get the strings with more than 3 words:

```
cnt <- stri_count(string,regex="\\S+")
string[cnt>=3]
[1] "Hij is op 22 oktober 2001 getrouwd"
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Still wondering why my regexes don't work, but at least this gets me the desired result! You should think that `(\\b\\.\\b){3,}` should do the job, at least in theory, right?

Comment: @Raoul `" Biografie "` has two spaces, that's why you get 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option with `gregexpr`

```
lengths(gregexpr("\\w+", string)) * nzchar(string)
#[1] 0 7 0 1
```

#### data

```
string <- c("", "Hij is op 22 oktober 2001 getrouwd", "", " Biografie ")
```